# Is it possible to test flow using Protractor without login flow?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to test flow using Protractor which occurs after login page, can I bypass or skip or avoid login while testing that flow?

Comment: protractor simulates a users behaviour on your website. if you can avoid logging in, there is a security issue on your website. why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: implement fast login if you really need it in your application (via URL params of smth)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to instead of opening a fresh browser instance each test, you open Firefox loading the Firefox profile previously saved when you was logged in. Aside from many other things, the profile contains cookies, that are usually used for login session validation:

- log in to your application via Firefox
- open Help->Troubleshooting Information->Profile Folder->Show in Finder (for Mac OS)
- copy the path to the profile
- use [`setFirefoxProfile`](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) HowTo to learn how to load this profile every time you run your tests

Answer (score 0):

You can always **mock** the login, where details will depend on how the login is implemented.

If it is the session or key returned by the server, you can mock the server response by supplying that key, that will be accepted by your front end code, as if there was successful login.